# Find all positive real solutions of the system

Tags: calculus, inequality, systems-of-equations, contest-math, tangent-line-method

> Find all positive real solutions of the system of equations
>   $$\begin{cases}
> x_1+x_2+...+x_{1994}=1994 \\
> x_1^4+x_2^4+...+x_{1994}^4=x_1^3+x_2^3+....+x_{1994}^3
> \end{cases}$$

''By Hölder, we have in general
$(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)(x_1^3+\dots+x_n^3) \le n \cdot (x_1^4+\dots+x_n^4)$ with equality iff the $x_i$ are all equal.
So in this case we must have $x_1=\dots=x_{1994}=1$.''

Theory a more algebraic solution? (sum, subtraction, etc ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $$ x^4-x^3\geq x-1$$

with equality iff $x=1$. Let
$$E:= x_1^4+x_2^4+...+x_{1994}^4-(x_1^3+x_2^3+....+x_{1994}^3)$$
So we have $$0=E\geq x_1+...+x_{1994}-1994=0$$

and thus all $x_i=1$.

Comment: What did you use? Chebyshev's?

Comment: Nice solution, doesn’t seem to even use positivity of the $x_i$ +1

Comment: no, i draw a graph and a tangent at x=1

Comment: Thanks for the solution!